# Create a rectangle that can change it's name using loop in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to create several rectangles (with dynamic names) by changing the name of the rectangle

```
int[] num= { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; //I need infant number of rectangle but here only a symbol of four numbers.  
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1)
{
    string  mystring= "regctangle"+num[i].ToString();
    string  rectanglename = myString; //this is the rectangle name change with the loop
    Rectangle rectanglename= new Rectangle(10, 10, 3, 3);
}
```

The results should be  for first iteration rectangle

rectangle1

rectangle2

rectangle3

rectangle4

Comment: variable names can only be set by the programmer. dynamic varible names are not possible. if you need to accees any thing by a uique string you can put it in a Dictionary<string, yourthingtype>

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think what you are asking is possible. C# does not allow you to declare a variable as one type and then redeclare it as another. In this case `rectanglename` as type `string` and then as type `Rectangle`. My suggestion would be to create a list of key value pairs to hold your Rectangles. The key would be your name and the value would be the rectangle. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This questions is kind of interesting...here's some options I came up with, since I'm not sure what your intention is with having these unique variable names.

What you'd need to do is either:
1) Add the rectangle to a dictionary or 
2) Add a name property to the Rectangle class.

I did both on the code below.

```
//dictionary for our rectangles
var rectangleDict = new Dictionary<string, Rectangle>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1)
{
    var rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 10, 3, 3);    
    string  rectangleName = "rectangle" + i.ToString();

    //add rectangle name to new dictionary entry and the Rectangle name property
    rectangle.name = rectangleName;
    rectangleDict[rectangleName] = rectangle;           
}
```

Once you got that set up here are a couple of options on how to look up those rectangles and their properties.

```
//#1 Use the dict to iterate through them
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Rectangle> rect in rectangleDict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(rect.Key);    
    //iterate through any property in the rectangle such as its sides, name, etc
    Console.WriteLine(rect.Value.name);
}

//#2 use the key directly to access a property
Console.WriteLine(rectangleDict["rectangle1"].name);
```

Comment: I solved it by Add a name property to the Rectangle class. T

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first problem here is how are you going to label the rectangles? Based on the [MSDN api documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) for Rectangle, there is no property that you can use for storing custom names.

Just a thought, there can be a better solution out there. You can potentially extend the Rectangle class, throw in a variable call "name" or something, then write the setters and getters operators for it.

Then in your code when you need to print the label just do.

```
int[] num= { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++)
{
     MyRectangle rectanglename = new MyRectangle("NAME_XXX", 10, 10, 3, 3);
     // Probably push the instance into an array for later reference.
}

// When you need the rectangle's name just do something like
console.writeline(rectangle10.name);
```

Apologise here. My unix laptop don't have a copy of visual studio installed so I can't really show you a proper piece of code, only pseudo code.